# Angular promises run conditionally

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I'd like to perform an asynch function conditionally, but I think I'm missing the correct syntax to say what I want.

```
this.doUpToThreeThings = function(skipTheMiddleStep) {
    return doFirstThing().then(function (result) {
        if (skipTheMiddleStep) {
            return doThirdThing();
        } else {
            return doSecondThing();
        }
    }).then(function (result) {
        if (skipTheMiddleStep) {
            return "ok"; // return what?
        } else {
            return doThirdThing();
        }
    });
}
```

By the time we get to the second then, I don't know if the first block did the middle step, so I'm forced into repeating the condition.  And the second block reads weird: it should say, if skip the middle step, then do the third thing, but since it we know that the previous block must have done the third thing, it just returns.  So I have to repeat the condition and write pretty wrong-looking code in the second then.

I realize I can write a function called doSecondAndThirdThings, and just call that from the condition in the first block, but that's not really DRY, it's just hiding the non-DRYness.  (or maybe I'm wrong about that?)

Also, I'm still a little confused about returning a completed promise on that "ok" branch.  Is that right how it is, or should I say something like resolve?  -- Thanks

Comment: I'll fix the question or remove it if the downvoter would kindly explain the vote.

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvote, but I will say I don't understand what you're asking about.  I don't "See the problem" from the code you shared; and I'm just confused.  And as such, I don't understand what issue you're trying to resolve.  I haven't thought much about promise objects, so perhaps the problem in understanding is me.

Comment: @JeffryHouser - thanks.  I did my best to clarify.

Comment: Your question was good and clear on the first iteration too. I think the person who downvoted it simply did not understand it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The deferred in thefourtheye's answer is pointless and is considered an anti pattern with promises.

Here is how I would do it:

```
this.doUpToThreeThings = function(skipTheMiddleStep) {
    return doFirstThing().then(function (result) {
        return (skipTheMiddleStep) ? doThirdThing() : doSecondThing().then(doThirdThing);
    });
}
```

Comment: Ah, I can answer a then from inside a then.  That makes sense now that I see it.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Minor syntax fix: that nested doThridThing needs () parens.  I sure wish there was a doc I could use that listed common patterns with code.  e.g. here's how to do 2 things in parallel, then a third, here's how to collect intermediate results, here's how to ... This is great stuff, but very abstract to learn (especially if you've been coding a long time without it).

Comment: Nope, the nested doThirdThing absolutely must not be given parens. BG got it right.

Comment: By the way BG, it's not universally true that Deferred objects don't have a `.then` method. Some do, some don't, depending on lib - [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2NJ4R/). The proposals, Promises/A and Promises/A+, don't delve into Deferreds or Promise creation in general, so it's not a question of compliance. Personally, I believe that a Deferred should have a superset of the methods of any Promise(s) which it spawns, ie a Deferred should have a `.then` method.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot When I answer an Angular $q question what I mean by "deferred objects" is ["$q's deferred objects"](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L205) which don't have `.then` method. If you'd like to discuss APIs then SO isn't really the place for that but you're very welcome to come to #promises in irc.freenode - personally, I believe that old API should die in favor of the promise constructor and things like Bluebird's `Promise.method`. Moreover jQuery's promise API is rather horrible :D Btw, here's spec https://github.com/promises-aplus/constructor-spec

Comment: How did I know you'd take the opportunity to have toot at jQuery? It's really not that bad. :D

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot or BG, could you explain .then(doThirdThing) vs .then(doThirdThing()) vs .then(function () { doThirdThing(); } ?  esp, what if I need to send params?

Comment: If you need to send params you can do the latter or `.bind` , doing `fnName()` _calls_ a function, doing `fnName` passes it.

Comment: `doThirdThing` will naturally accept as a param, the value returned by `doSecondThing`, or the value with which a promise returned by `doSecondThing` is resolved. To pass multiple parameters, then set properties of an object and return that object.