# NodeJS sequential async with conditional statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, q

Is it possible to write NodeJS code that executes several async steps in a sequential way, where some steps get executed or bypassed based on conditional statements?

Let me try to write an example in pseudo code.

Imagine you have something like

`step1.then(step2).then(step3);`

Now let's add an option:

`var opt = true;`

How is it possible to achieve something like:

`step1.then(opt && step2).then(step3);`

Or, if we had let's say 2 different possible steps in the middle:

`step1.then(opt ? step2 : step3).then(step4);`

**EDIT**

If the optional step was at the beginning instead?

`(opt && step1).then(step2).then(step3);`

It would be awesome if anyone could shed some light or come up with proposals!

Thanks

Comment: Probably duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594978/angular-promises-run-conditionally (not going to close now since you already got an answer anyway)

Comment: Dpends on when you want the `opt` to be evaluated. If it's statically known, your ternary operator would already work, and that `opt &&` could be written as either `(opt ? step1.then(step2) : step1).then(step3)` or `step1.then(opt ? step2 : function id(x){ return x; }).then(step3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `step2` and `step3` are functions returning a promise what is the problem with:

```
 step1.then(function() {
     if( opt ) {
         return step2();
     } else {
         return step3();
     }
 })
 .then(step4);
```

**EDIT**

Your first example `step1.then(opt && step2).then(step3);` would look like this:

```
step1.then(function() {
     if( opt ) {
         return step2();
     }
 })
 .then(step3);
```

If you don't return anything then `undefined` is returned. For every returned value that is not a Promise, the library will create a Promise that is resolved with that value.

[Promises/A+: The then Method](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-41):

> `promise2 = promise1.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);`
>
> If either `onFulfilled` or `onRejected` returns a value `x`, run the Promise Resolution Procedure `[[Resolve]](promise2, x)`.

Comment: Just what I was about to write, this is the correct way to go.

Comment: This seems to properly handle the second example in my question. How would you manage the first one though?

`step1.then(opt && step2).then(step3);`

If I understand correctly, this case would not return a promise when `var opt = false`. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks! That's the bit of information that I was missing  :)
I didn't know that the library would automatically generate a promise in case the returned value is not already one.

Comment: Just a last question: what would happen in case you have the "optional step" at the very beginning? In pseudo-code
`(opt && step1).then(step2).then(step3);`

Comment: @Pensierinmusica: Then use `Q(opt && step1()).then(…)`

Comment: @t.niese: I think the first example would be well represented by `step1().then(function() { return opt || step2(); }).…` (instead of that `if`)

Comment: @Bergi I probably might write it that way in my code but as some people don't know the meaning of `opt || step2()` I have chosen the more verbose version using `if`